# How to Supply Default Value back to DataGridViewCell After Error Message

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, error-checking

My current code will show a messagebox that tells the user that only numeric input will be accepted if they input any non-integer into the field. However I can't seem to find out how I might supply a default value back to the datagridviewcell.

```
Private Sub DataGridViewCOTS_DataError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewCOTS.DataError

    If StrComp(e.Exception.Message, "Input string was not in a correct format.") = 0 Then

        'If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a numeric Value")


        'DataGridViewCOTS.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = 3

    End If





End Sub
```

Comment: Execute a trim on the string retrieved to remove the (possibly) whitespaces

Comment: So try something like this?: myString = myString.Trim()

Comment: Dim value As String = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.Trim()

Comment: Yes, but you should be sure that Value doesn't contains null values (Nothing)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue

Comment: Let me update what I have so far

Comment: Alright now I'm able to show the message to the user when they input a letter, however I want to supply a default value back to the datagridcell after the message pops up. I'm hoping to have the default value set to 3, the DataGridViewCOTS.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = 3, doesn't work for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ca2b3a41-e598-4a84-ac75-57064febd5e5/change-cell-value-in-datagridviewdataerror

> The DataError event occurs when an external data-parsing or validation
> operation throws an exception, or when an attempt to commit data to a
> data source fails.
>
> Based on it, you can't fix the value here since the
> value will not be committed. After you changed the correct/default
> value to the DataGridView Cell, you must commit it. **So, set the
> e.Cancel = false would be OK**.

So, just set `e.Cancel = false` after you change value and it should work.

Hope this helps